# How to avoid memory leaks when using getline to read from stdin in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I am encountering memory leaks when using getline to read from stdin in C, despite ensuring that all the mallocs were freed, the problem  persists when building a simple shell. As someone who is new to C, I am looking for advice on how to properly handle memory when using getline for file input.

This is the code i used to read the line

```
char *readline(int *eof)
{
    char *input = NULL;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    *eof = getline(&input, &bufsize, stdin);
    return (input);
}
```

this is the actual main function.

```
    while (status)
    {
        mode = isatty(STDIN_FILENO);
        if (mode != 0)
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "$ ", 3);
        }
        line = readline(&eof);
        if (eof == -1)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        args = tokenize(line);
        status = hsh_execute(args, env, argv[0]);
        i = 0;
        while(args[i] != NULL)
        {
            free(args[i]);
            i++;
        }
        free(args);
        free(line);
    }
```

this is the error returned by valgrind when i run the command echo "/bin/ls" | ./shell

```
==33899== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==33899==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==33899==    by 0x10980D: main (shell.c:40)
==33899==  Address 0x4a96040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==33899==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==33899==    by 0x1097D5: main (shell.c:36)
==33899==  Block was alloc'd at
==33899==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==33899==    by 0x48EB1A2: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:62)
==33899==    by 0x1096CA: readline (readline.c:12)
==33899==    by 0x10976B: main (shell.c:26)
==33899== 
==33899== 
==33899== HEAP SUMMARY:
==33899==     in use at exit: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==33899==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 4,848 bytes allocated
==33899== 
==33899== LEAK SUMMARY:
==33899==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==33899==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==33899==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==33899==    still reachable: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==33899==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==33899== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==33899== 
==33899== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==33899== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Regarding the realloc problem this is how i handled it in the tokenize function

```
#define BUFSIZE 64
#define DELIM " \t\r\n\a"
char **tokenize(char *line)
{
    /*declaration of various fucntions*/
    char **toks = malloc(sizeof(char *) * BUFSIZE);
    int position = 0;
    char *token, **token_backup;
    int bufsize = BUFSIZE;

    /*allocation error*/
    if (toks == NULL)
    {
        free(toks);
        perror("hsh");
    }
    token = strtok(line, DELIM);
    /*Store  token in toks*/
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        toks[position] = token;
        position++;
        /*not enough memory*/
        if (position >= BUFSIZE)
        {
            bufsize += BUFSIZE;
            token_backup = toks;
            toks = realloc(toks, position * sizeof(char *));
            if (toks == NULL)
            {
                free(token_backup);
                printf("allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
    }
    toks[position] = NULL;
    return (toks);
}
```

Comment: The code related to `getline`, and the corresponding `free` look ok. You do have a lot of other memory allocation going on. Why do you think that it's `line` that's being leaked?

Comment: i edited it and added the valgrind error. i did realloc in the tokenize function  could that cause the memory leak?

Comment: my guess, tokenize uses strtok and so retrns an array of pointers pointing at line

Comment: I think we need to see a [mcve].

Comment: please show all the code in tokenize

Comment: IMO You should increasingly remove some code in order to find the error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a memory leak.  You're freeing memory that was already freed.

```
    i = 0;
    while(args[i] != NULL)
    {
        free(args[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(args);
    free(line);
```

Each `args[i]` is a pointer to somewhere inside of `line`.  They were not allocated individually.

So get rid of the loop and *only* free `args` and `line`.

Comment: i got rid of the loop as you said but i am still losing 120 bytes. Valgrind keeps saying that 120 bytes is still reachable.Is that normal

Comment: That's from some other allocation you haven't shown us.  Run valgrind with `--leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes` and it will tell you the source.

Comment: i ran it with this ```--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all``` the first time and got the same message except the 4 frees changed into 3.Also the lauch function just calls execve with no allocs

Answer (score 1):

I guess the line

```
char *readline(int *eof)
```

should be

```
char *readline(ssize_t *eof)
```

and `eof` should be declared accordingly.

Comment: @user3386109 Yep you're right !

Answer (score 1):

my guess was correct, you are using strtok. strtok will return pointers to the input buffer. So `argv[0]` is the same as `line`. So you in fact ended up deleting `line` twice

Answer (score 0):

The `tokenize` function does not allocate the individual strings in the allocated array it returns.  This explains explain how `line` is freed twice: by `free(args[i])` when `i` is `0` and `free(line)` at the end of `main`. Furthermore, if the line has more than one word or if it starts with spaces, you are calling `free` with pointers that point inside an allocated block, which has undefined behavior.

The `tokenize` function has problems too:

- when you reallocate the array, you pass the wrong size: instead of `position * sizeof(char *)` you should pass `bufsize * sizeof(char *)`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* getline wrapper with a different API */
ssize_t readline(char **linep) {
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    *linep = NULL;
    return = getline(linep, &bufsize, stdin);
}

#define BUFSIZE 64
#define DELIM " \t\r\n\a"
char **tokenize(char *line) {
    /* declaration of various variables */
    int bufsize = BUFSIZE;
    int position = 0;
    char **toks = malloc(sizeof(char *) * bufsize);
    char *token, **token_backup;

    if (toks == NULL) {
        /* allocation error */
        perror("cannot allocate array");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* break line into tokens and store them in toks */
    token = strtok(line, DELIM);
    while (token != NULL) {
        toks[position] = token;
        position++;
        if (position >= BUFSIZE) {
            /* need more space */
            bufsize += BUFSIZE;
            token_backup = toks;
            toks = realloc(toks, sizeof(char *) * bufsize);
            if (toks == NULL) {
                free(token_backup);
                perror("cannot reallocate array");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
    }
    toks[position] = NULL;
    return toks;
}

char **env = NULL;
int hsh_execute(char **args, char **env, char *command);

int main(void) {
    int status = 1;

    while (status) {
        char *line;
        char **args;

        if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "$ ", 3);
        }
        if (readline(&line) == -1) {
            // end of file reached
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        args = tokenize(line);
        status = hsh_execute(args, env, argv[0]);
        free(args);
        free(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```